# how to check that I am using c3p0 in hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, c3p0

I am change my hibernate.cfg.xml added new options:

```
<property name="connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/pirates</property>
        <property name="connection.username">postgres</property>
        <property name="connection.password">mmm888</property>

        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>
        <property name="show_sql">false</property>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">200</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">300</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">3000</property>
        <property name="hibernate.generate_statistics">true</property>
```

and added hibernate-c3p0-4.1.4.Final.yar in my project, but I'm not sure that I'm using c3p0. I can set hibernate.c3p0.max_size = 2 but Hibernate continues to create 400 ( 400 -for example) threads - if it needs to.

**how to check that I am using c3p0 in hibernate ?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing this line:

```
<property name="connection.provider_class"  
   value="org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider"/>
```

This tells Hibernate to use the C3P0 connection pool.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure the above answer is necessary, according to C3P0ConnectionProvider document:

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/connection/C3P0ConnectionProvider.html

It says:

"A connection provider that uses a C3P0 connection pool. Hibernate will use this by default if the hibernate.c3p0.* properties are set."

Answer (score 0):

Check [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#database-connectionprovider).

> Generally speaking, applications should not have to configure a
>   ConnectionProvider explicitly if using one of the Hibernate-provided
>   implementations. Hibernate will internally determine which
>   ConnectionProvider to use based on the following algorithm:
>
> If hibernate.connection.provider_class is set, it takes precedence
>
> else if hibernate.connection.datasource is set → Using DataSources
>
> else if any setting prefixed by hibernate.c3p0. is set → Using c3p0
>
> else if any setting prefixed by hibernate.proxool. is set → Using
>   Proxool
>
> else if any setting prefixed by hibernate.hikari. is set → Using
>   Hikari
>
> else if hibernate.connection.url is set → Using Hibernate’s built-in
>   (and unsupported) pooling
>
> else → User-provided Connections

Other than this, the fastest way to check is to go in database server and see whether the idle connection have been created or not.